# Custom button for edit state of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

The standard behaviour for the editing state of a UITableView is to show a red minus, which when tapped brings up a delete button. Is there a way to customize this, whereby the minus button is a custom one, and the 'delete' confirmation does not appear?

Comment: Rather I would recommend you to swipe delete your tableview rows. As it minimizes the number of clicks(touches) required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove or change (but still use a standard editing accessory), use:

```
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
```

To provide your own image/view, use:

```
cell.editingAccessoryView = yourView; //yourView can be an UIImageView
```

Comment: This is the `editingAccessoryType` (displayed right), the minus is the `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` (displayed left).

Answer (score 0):

You could customize the whole edit process: Add a edit-Button to the nav bar. Add an action. On action change the appearance of the cells as you like. Call reloadData.